# Upgrade GDAL on Google Colab

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory, gdal, python-wheel

I want to upgrade GDAL on google colab which currently on version 3.7.2, but in google colab is still 3.4.3. After surfing on the internet, I found [issue](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/3375) on github regarding to this point. I Try to follow the instruction but I got this error:

```
Collecting GDAL==3.7.2
  Downloading GDAL-3.7.2.tar.gz (777 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 777.0/777.0 kB 9.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: GDAL
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for GDAL (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for GDAL
  Running setup.py clean for GDAL
Failed to build GDAL
ERROR: Could not build wheels for GDAL, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Anyone know what is going on? And how to solve the error?

Comment: Although it seems like more work, you are most likely better off installing gdal using a conda environment, which will require installing miniconda.